# Angular Typescript to Http JSON mapping

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http

What patterns to use to map results from API to Typescript class, like a decorator, etc, do not want to create exact replica Typescript class/JSON object to match the backend java object.

TypeScript

```
export interface ISearchResult {
  Id: string;
  name: string;
  startDate?: Moment;
  endDate?: Moment;
  status?: string;
  count?: number;
  offeringCount?: number;
}

export class SearchResult implements ISearchResult {
  Id: string;
  name: string;
  startDate?: Moment;
  endDate?: Moment;
  status?: string;
  count?: number;
  offeringCount?: number;
}
```

Results from API are. Basically, it's not one to one mapping.

Is there a way I can add some annotation in my TypeScript to map to the Object below?

```
[
    {
        "product": [
            {
                "productPolicy": {},
                "productDetails": [
                    {
                        "id": "30016719",
                        "statusIndicator": true,
                        "productExists": false,
                        "productName": "ABC",
                         "address": {
                            "city": "Denver",
                            "stateCode": "CO"
                        },
                        "payIndicator": false,
                        "productDelted": false,
                        "membershipGroupingSalesData": {},
                        "statusCode": "A

                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
```

Comment: your TS interface and API do not match ?